# Check if all Values of an array are the interger 1

Tags: c#, arrays

Im trying to use Array.All or array.TrueforAll to see if all the values in my array are 1. I can seem to get it to work

```
bool allAreOne = Array.TrueForAll(globalVariables.singlePeriodClasses, value = 1);
```

but i get the error that "value" does not exist... not quite sure how to use this method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
bool allAreOne = Array.TrueForAll(
                   globalVariables.singlePeriodClasses, 
                   value => value == 1);
```

The second parameter is the *predicate* that defines the conditions to check against the elements. Keep in mind that, ***A predicate is a function that returns true or false***.

> The Predicate is a delegate to a method that returns true if the
>   object passed to it matches the conditions defined in the delegate.
>   The elements of array are individually passed to the Predicate, and
>   processing is stopped when the delegate returns false for any element.

Read more from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2kykt9x(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to understand the MSDN article but was getting seriously confused! thanks for helpin out!

Answer (score 4):

The [`TrueForAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2kykt9x(v=vs.110).aspx) method expects a [delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx) (in this case a [`Predicate<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfcke1bz(v=vs.110).aspx)). The easiest way to provide one is with a [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) (`=>`). Also, take note of the difference between the [assignment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbkb459w.aspx) (`=`) and [equality](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53k8ybth.aspx) (`==`) operators:

```
bool allAreOne = Array.TrueForAll(
    globalVariables.singlePeriodClasses, 
    value => value == 1);
```